# owl carousel 2 custom nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm using owl carousel 1 plugin and I'm trying to upgrade all my stuff to version 2. I have a slider with a custom navbar:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function customPager() {
        $.each(this.owl.userItems, function (i) {
            var titleData = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('title');
            var paginationLinks = jQuery('.owl-controls .owl-pagination .owl-page span');

            $(paginationLinks[i]).append(titleData);
        });
    }

    $('.rri-carousel').owlCarousel({
        navigation      : false, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed      : 300,
        paginationSpeed : 400,
        singleItem      : true,
        lazyLoad        : true,
        afterInit       : customPager,
        afterUpdate     : customPager,
        transitionStyle : "fade",
        autoPlay        : true,
        stopOnHover     : true
    });
});
```

How do I convert this to owl carousel 2? I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function customPager() {
        $.each(this.owl.userItems, function (i) {
            var titleData = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('title');
            var paginationLinks = jQuery('.owl-controls .owl-pagination .owl-page span');

            $(paginationLinks[i]).append(titleData);
        });
    }

    $('.rri-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop          : true,
        items         : 1,
        nav           : false,
        onInitialized : customPager,
        onResized     : customPager

    });
});
```

However I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userItems' of undefined` in the chrome console and when I click it it shows the error is on `$.each(this.owl.userItems, function (i) {` on `this.owl.userItems`.

I'm assuming that function was removed to changed in the update but I cannot figure any of this out, I'm new to javascript.

Not only do I get this error, I also don't see any pager like I did in the first version.

Thanks and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

EDIT:

I copied your javascript but still no pagination.. Here is my php that outputs the html:

```
function rri_function($type = 'rri_function') {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'rri_images',
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    );

    $result = '<div class="rri-carousel owl-theme">';

    //the loop
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) {
        $loop->the_post();

        $the_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), $type);
        $result .= '<div><img src="' . $the_url[0] . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '" data-thumb="' . $the_url[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '"></div>';
    }
    $result .= '</div>';

    return $result;
}
```

and here is what gets printed on the page:

prev
                next

Comment: i can't see any problem here, could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: @EmreTürkiş I cannot seem to link the owl carousel javascript file to jsfiddle

Comment: take a look at this and add as external library: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/owl-carousel

Comment: That site only has version 1 of owl carousel. I'm trying to upgrade to version 2 because there is an issue in version 1 that is fixed in version 2.

Comment: the error message indicates that 'owl' is not defined on 'this' at that line. 'this' refers to the function customPager and there is indeed nothing named owl. I'll post it as an answer. it's becoming hard to do as a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am new to javascript but this worked for me. Owl carousel 2 has different CSS classes: **.owl-dots .owl-dot** instead of **.owl-controls .owl-pagination .owl-page**

I've also changed **this.owl.userItems** to **$('.owl-item')** to select each carousel item (not sure whether this is appropriate solution).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function customPager() {
        $.each($('.owl-item'), function (i) {
            var titleData = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('title');
            var paginationLinks = jQuery('.owl-dots .owl-dot span');

            $(paginationLinks[i]).append(titleData);
    });
}

$('.rri-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop          : true,
        items         : 1,
        nav           : false,
        onInitialized : customPager,
     });
});
```

EDIT: I have removed **onResized: customPager** parameter because it was repeatedly adding new links after existing ones when resizing browser window. However I am not shure what was the purpose of this parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that 'owl' is not defined on 'this' aka customPager function. And actually no variable named 'owl' is defined anywhere in your code. I looked up at the documentation of owl-carousel 2.0 and I guess you need something like this.

```
var owl = $('.rri-carousel');
```

and I didn't see any variable named 'userItems' in the documentation. But you can use jquery to access the elements. to put things in perspective,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var owl = $('.rri-carousel');

    function customPager() {
        $.each($(owl).find('.item'), function (i) {
            var titleData = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('title');
            var paginationLinks = jQuery('.owl-controls .owl-pagination .owl-page span');
            $(paginationLinks[i]).append(titleData);
        });
    }

    owl.owlCarousel({
        loop          : true,
        items         : 1,
        nav           : false,
        onInitialized : customPager,
        onResized     : customPager
    });
});
```

I can't fully test whether it's working or not because I don't have your html to test it with, but I'm having no problems with this code on my machine.

Comment: I updated my original question post with my HTML, and PHP stuff. I copied your javascript over but still don't see the pagination with text. Really appreciate the help though, and hopefully we can figure this out

Comment: Cool news! I got it working. BUT the titles arent in the right order

Comment: glad you made it man. you can ask another question about ordering by the way